# encodeURI function doesn't encode parenthesis “( )”

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to load a background image under a js code as mentioned below:

```
$('.main-banner').css('background-image', "url("+encodeURI(element.image)+")");
```

Unfortunately, if the image name `element.image` contains some parenthesis: `(` or `)` this will cause a problem, and the image will not load.

Comment: The _actual_ problem here is not really URL encoding though. (Although they _should_ be encoded, browsers know how to handle non-encoded `(` and `)` in URLs fine.) The _context_ URL is not the problem here, the context _CSS Syntax_ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`encodeURI` will not encode the parentheses, Try to replace them manually like :

```
const url = element.image.replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29");
$('.main-banner').css('background-image', "url("+encodeURI(url)+")");
```

Using the `encodeURI` method before the replacement will be like :

```
const url = encodeURI(element.image).replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29");
$('.main-banner').css('background-image', "url("+url+")");
```

Comment: In fact by this way we encode the %29 it becomes %2529 this will not work , it should be encodeUri then replace